# Utilizing OrientDB ETL to create 2 vertices and a connected edge at every line of CSV

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm utilizing OrientDB ETL tool to import a large amount of data in GBs. The format of the CSV is such that ( I'm using orientDB 2.2 ) :

"101.186.130.130","527225725","233 djfnsdkj","0.119836317542"
"125.143.534.148","112212983","1227 sdfsdfds","0.0465215171983"
"103.149.957.752","112364761","1121 sdfsdfds","0.0938863016658"
"103.190.245.128","785804692","6138 sdfsdfsd","0.117767539364"

I'm required to create Two vertices one with the value in Column1(key being the value itself) and another Vertex having values in column 2 & 3 ( Its key concatenated with both values and both present as attributes in the second vertex type, the 4th column will be the property of the edge connecting both of these vertices.

I used the below code and it works ok with some errors, one problem is all values in each csv row is stored as properties within the IpAddress vertex, Is there any way to store only the IpAddress in it. Secondly please can you let me know the method to concatenate two values read from the csv.

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "/home/abcd/OrientDB/examples/ip_address.csv" } },
 "extractor": { "csv": {"columnsOnFirstLine": false, "columns":     ["ip:string", "dpcb:string", "address:string", "prob:string"] } },
 "transformers": [
{ "merge": { "joinFieldName":"ip", "lookup":"IpAddress.ip" } },
{ "edge": { "class": "Located",
            "joinFieldName": "address",
            "lookup": "PhyLocation.loc",
            "direction": "out",
    "targetVertexFields": { "geo_address": "${input.address}", "dpcb_number": "${input.dpcb}"},
        "edgeFields": { "confidence": "${input.prob}" },
        "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
        }
    }
 ],
"loader": {
"orientdb": {
   "dbURL": "remote:/localhost/Bulk_Transfer_Test",
   "dbType": "graph",
   "dbUser": "root",
   "dbPassword": "tiger",
   "serverUser": "root",
   "serverPassword": "tiger",
   "classes": [
     {"name": "IpAddress", "extends": "V"},
     {"name": "PhyLocation", "extends": "V"},
 {"name": "Located", "extends": "E"}
   ], "indexes": [
     {"class":"IpAddress", "fields":["ip:string"], "type":"UNIQUE" },
 {"class":"PhyLocation", "fields":["loc:string"], "type":"UNIQUE" }
   ]
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you post an example snippet of you csv file? Thx

Comment: @Ivan Thanksfor responding, just updated the sample file

Comment: Have you take a look at this? http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/ETL-Introduction.html
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Transformer.html

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I checked the documentation, i couldn't find sufficient examples for it. Like for example merging two columns.

Comment: @all Thanks for the comments, i was able to create a script and do a part of the work. There are couple of issues still, please can you help in it.